# Bug tracking software with rest/java api's

Tags: workflow, bug-tracking

Hi please suggest me an opensource workflow management software which provide either rest/java api's so that it can be integrated with my existing application to automate the bug tracking process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm using [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org) and it's Fork [ChiliProject](https://www.chiliproject.org/)

Both offer you an [REST API](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_api) for several tasks.